# In AppleScript, how can you tell if an app has finished loading after it is launched?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have some AppleScript-based automation around an application (specifically, [Zotero](https://zotero.org), in case it matters). If the application is not running, I need to start it. This particular application takes significant time to finish loading, which means I have to make sure the rest of the automation workflow waits before it tries to communicate with the app.

Currently, the approach I'm using is to include a hardcoded delay that I *hope* is long enough. The code is basically this:

```
tell application "Zotero"
  if it is not running then
    launch
    repeat until application "Zotero" is running
      delay 0.5
    end repeat
    -- For me, Zotero takes a long time to load even after it's
    -- launched. I haven't found a way to test it's done, so
    -- all I can do is use a delay here & hope for the best.
    delay 15
  end if
end tell
```

Having a hardcoded delay is suboptimal. This leads to my question: **is there a way to detect that an application has finished starting after it has been `launch`ed from AppleScript?**

Comment: Does the application show a startup screen or something other than a regular window while it is loading?

Comment: @red_menace Good question. The application does show its full normal screen, but for a while there are parts that say "loading", and the thing is generally unresponsive. (Also, to clearify, I'm looking for a programmatic solution, not one that relies on seeing the thing.)

Comment: Unless the application itself has such an interface, you're primarily limited to watching for it to draw its windows.

Comment: Zotero has a minimal scripting dictionary, and System Events can use the Accessibility frameworks to get various information about windows, such as their title.  If there is something that _you_ can use to determine if the app has finished loading, perhaps there is also something in one of those.

Comment: @red_menace Yeah, I think basically that's what it comes down to doing …